# How can I modify multiple Mongoose collections simultaneously?

Tags: mongoose, collections

I have 3 Mongoose collection: Board, Thread and Reply. Each Reply belongs to 1 Thread (as an array's item in "replies" property)  and each Thread belongs to 1 Board (as an array's item in "threads" property).

As the code below, whenever I want to add a new Reply to the database by sending a post request, I have to update all 3 collections: Board, Thread and Reply.

Is there any other way to achive this without having to manually modify each collection one by one?

```js
app.route('/api/replies/:board').post(async (req, res) => {
    const { text, delete_password, thread_id } = req.body;
    const board = req.params.board;
    
    if (!thread_id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
      res.send('Thread ID is invalid');
    } else {
      const updateBoard = await BoardModel.findOne({name: board}).exec(); //find the Board in Board collection
      const updateThread = updateBoard.threads.id(thread_id); //find the Thread in that Board
      const updateThreadDB = await ThreadModel.findById(thread_id).exec(); //find the Thread in Thread collection
      if (!updateThreadDB || !updateBoard) {
        res.send("Board or thread not found");
      } else {
        //Add new Reply
        const newReply = new ReplyModel({
          text: text,
          delete_password: delete_password,
          reported: false,
        })
        let saveReply = await newReply.save(); //save Reply to Reply collection

        //Update Thread and Board
        updateThreadDB.replies.push(saveReply);
        updateThread.replies.push(saveReply);
        let saveBoard = await updateBoard.save(); //update new Board collection
        let saveThread = await updateThreadDB.save(); //update new Thread collection

        res.json(saveReply);
      }
    }
  })
```

Here's my models file:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB);
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const replySchema = new Schema ({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
  created_on: {type : Date, required: true, default: () => { return new Date() }},
  delete_password: {type: String, required: true},
  reported: {type: Boolean, required: true},
})
const Reply = mongoose.model('Reply', replySchema);

const threadSchema = new Schema ({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
  created_on: {type : Date, required: true, default: () => { return new Date() }},
  bumped_on: {type : Date, required: true, default: () => { return new Date() }},
  reported: {type: Boolean, required: true},
  delete_password: {type: String, required: true},
  replies: {type: [replySchema], required: true},
});
const Thread = mongoose.model('Thread', threadSchema);

const boardSchema = new Schema ({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  threads: {type: [threadSchema], required: true},
});
const Board = mongoose.model('Board', boardSchema);

exports.Board = Board;
exports.Thread = Thread;
exports.Reply = Reply;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the your schemas and the way you are storing the data seems like you are duplicating the data. For example you are creating a new `Reply` in your `replies` collection here:

```js
let saveReply = await newReply.save();
```

Then you are adding that same data twice. Once to the `threds.replies` array in the `threads` collection, and then once to the `boards.threads` array in the `boards` collection here:

```js
updateThreadDB.replies.push(saveReply);
updateThread.replies.push(saveReply);
let saveBoard = await updateBoard.save();
let saveThread = await updateThreadDB.save();
```

Mogodb documents are [limited to 16MB in size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) so if your application is popular you could end up exceeding the size of each `boards` document storing all those `threads` and nested `replies` in a single doument.

You need to make use of two things, [referenced documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) and [Model.findByIdAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findByIdAndUpdate()).

You could update your schemas like so:

```js
const boardSchema = new Schema ({
   name: {
      type: String, 
      required: true
   },
   threads: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, //< Store the _id of the thread
      ref: 'Thread', //< This will reference the threads collection
   },
});

const threadSchema = new Schema ({
   text: {
      type: String, 
      required: true
   },
   //...
   replies: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, //< Store the _id of the reply
      ref: 'Reply', //< This will reference the replies collection
   },
});
```

Now when you create a `Thread` you only need to push the `_id` of the `Thread`, which is an `ObjectId`, into the `Board.threads` **once**.

Then when you create a `Reply` you only need to push the `_id` of the `Reply`, which is an `ObjectId`, into the `Thread.replies` **once**.

Here is a sample of how you could create a new Thread for a Board:

```js
//Get the board _id
const boardId = req.params.board;

//Create a new Thread. Use create() instead of new and .save()
const thread = await Thread.create({
   text: req.body.text,
   //...
});

// Add the thread._id ObjectId into the board.threads array. 
// I have used findByIdAndUpdate() for demonstration 
const board = await Board.findByIdAndUpdate(boardId,
   { $push: { threads: thread._id } },
   { new: true }
);
```

Now you don't need to touch the `Board` document again until you need to delete a `Thread`.

Here is an example of how you can create a Reply:

```js
//Get the thread _id
const threadId = req.params.thread;

//Create a new Reply. Use create() instead of new and .save()
const reply = await Reply.create({
   text: req.body.text,
   //...
});

// Add the reply._id ObjectId into the thread.replies array. 
// I have used findByIdAndUpdate() for demonstration 
const thread = await Thread.findByIdAndUpdate(threadId,
   { $push: { replies: reply._id } },
   { new: true }
);
```

Notice how I didn't need to go and get the `Board` parent document. Now you can create as many replies as you want and only need to push the `_id` of each reply into the parent Thread. This will save so much space as only the `ObjectId` is being stored in the `Thread` and only the `ObjectId` being stored in each `Board`.

Lastly, if you want to get each referenced document you can use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). Please read it to understand but here is a sample of how you could do it:

```js
//Get the board _id
const boardId = req.params.board;

const board = await Board.findById(boardId)
.populate({
    path: 'threads', //< Replace all ObjectIds with the actual Thread document
    model: Thread,
    populate: {
        path: 'replies', //< Within each Thread replace all ObjectIds with the actual Reply document
        model: Reply
    },
});
```

Comment: Omg yeah I learned the referenced tables in SQL but yet have no idea about this in MongoDB. That's a lot of information for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, referenced document ids are synonymous with foreign keys in SQL but there is no "on delete cascade" so if you delete a thread for example you would need to get the ObjectIds within the replies array and use `$in` to `await Reply.deleteMany({_id: { $in: thread.replies}});`